# What is faster adding foreign key to an other table or creating flat table in select queries

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, select

I want to get the fastest way with select queries.
I have a table that contains two million lines and I want to add an information about the country for each line.
for exemple the table:
`strain(id,name,sequenceinformations,depositor,numberofsequences)`
and I want to add country informations: `country(id,name,code)`
what is the fastest way doing it in the same table or adding the country table and adding just id of country.
I know that for design it is better to separate tables and for maintenance it is mach better but in my case I search only the speed.

Comment: Did you try and test?

Comment: I will do this but I wanted to know your ideas and advices because may be there is some problems if I create a flat table this is the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age old normalization vs denormalization debate. At first glance, a separate table (the normalized approach) seems like the logical choice. However, for country data (which tends to be relatively static), adding it directly to the first table is a viable option. On the rare occasion when a country changes its name, the amount of maintenance is fairly minimal. Sure, it takes up more space, but space is cheap.

That said, for relatively small databases, the performance difference is probably negligible. Therefore, the best approach is whatever you find easiest to understand and maintain.

Also consider if the country information is likely to be used in other tables: if you're not careful, maintenance could become difficult and error prone.

So, to address your specific question: yes, a denormalized approach will, in most cases, be technically faster for select queries, but slower in update queries. Whether the difference is sufficient to justify it is another question.

As an aside, I saw an interesting approach recently where a separate table with country data was kept for the purpose of populated dropdown lists, etc, but the country name itself was added to the other tables. Obviously this approach isn't as robust as full normalization, but it certainly helped enforce a certain level of consistency.

Comment: thanks for your response Michael McMullin .For updates I don't have any problem because I will rewrite the data every mounth, so I am needing this table just for select it will be for statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Since your country table will not have rows more than countries in world so it will be small table so you can use separate table to have country data and use join to get the data.

I believe hash join will be a better option but since MySQL resolves all joins using nested-loop join. In nested loop join, The driving table is read once and for each row in driving table, the inner table is processed once.  The smaller the inner result set,better is the performance. So, you need to keep inner result from the country table.If inner input is indexed then it will be faster.

At last it depends on the factor how often your main table data is getting updated and selected. More updates go for new tables, lesser updates go for other approach.

Comment: I will try it and see. May be the best solution is to try both and compare performance.

Comment: after some trys I confirm that it is easier for me to put it in only one table because I have tested it for a case where there is 200000 lines related and it is craching with join.So the best solution is to have only one table and it is faster and mach more easier.

Comment: @Salihovic you chose the best option , that is to test both the approaches and it was very nice to share the results. now, you can accept michael's answer.